# String splitting while checking for containing words

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, split

This application is fairly simple ad I am not receviing any errors or warnings.
It only returns the word 'Hello' and wont move onto the word 'Bill'. It works by typing Hello and Bill.

Research:
[http://www.dotnetperls.com/split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx

Any tips or fixes would be awesome!

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Varaibles and Condition Types
        string WordiIntitalString = Console.ReadLine();
        //outputs "hello bill"
        char[] delimiterChars = { ' ' };
        string[] WordArray = WordiIntitalString.Split(delimiterChars);
        foreach(var word in WordArray)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(word);
            if (word.Equals("hello"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(word);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                if (word.Contains("bill"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("jarvis");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
```

The contains is attempting to look for a branch on top of the code. So if you do hello bill then it found find the branch. This inst very effective in my mind, but if you have any suggestions for a better method, id appreciate a comment!

Comment: because of your first `if`

Comment: Nor do I understand all the downvoting.  This gentleman has a question he cannot answer.  He was clear in what he wants answered and he provided code.  Don't downvote just because you think the question is too easy.

Comment: @bravosierra99 Look at the mouseover text for the down arrow: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." The downvoters clearly think that this does not reflect much effort, given how basic (and relatively obvious) the problem is.

Comment: @EdCottrell I think it's far too easy to forget how difficult code can be early on.  Since he's not getting an error it can be difficult to research if you are missing a key concept.  Obviously he doesn't understand nested conditionals.  Not sure why that means he should get a bunch of downvotes.  I guess that's just my opinion but considering this is supposed to be a place where you can go to ask questions, doesn't seem very inviting.

Comment: @bravosierra99 I agree that it's easy to forget how hard it is to learn to code. That said, it's pretty obvious that `word equals "hello"` and `word contains "bill"` can't both be true. This site welcomes questions from new programmers, but it's [supposed to be "a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers"](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). It's not a place to learn the most basic aspects of coding, like what braces after an `if` statement are for. Both you and I *did* try to answer OP's question, but that doesn't make it a well-researched question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have nested `if` statements with contradictory conditions. It's impossible to satisfy `word.Contains("bill")` if the same word also satisfied `word.Equals("hello")`.

In other words, if `word` gets into the first `if`, it can't possibly also get into the second one. That means your command `Console.WriteLine("jarvis")` is never reached.

Instead of nesting the `if`s, you probably meant to do them in the alternative:

```
if (word.Equals("hello"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
} else if (word.Contains("bill")) // <-- key change is here
{
    Console.WriteLine("jarvis");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Comment: I actually meant to do that, I'm trying to create a binary tree for millions of if statements. any way you suggest I do this

Comment: @JoeMeyer If you really need to check for millions of conditions, that means that you're very likely doing something wrong at a basic level. That is, your entire application strategy is probably wrong if you're checking millions of different conditions in text. In any case, you would need some sort of configuration or data file and a loop. You would obviously not want to hard-code all of those conditions. But how to do that is much too broad for a question here. If this answer helped, please remember to accept it. If you need additional help, you can ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

you have nested if's my friend

```
    foreach(var word in WordArray)  <-- 1st time word is hello, second time it's bill
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(word);
        if (word.Equals("hello"))  <-  let's hello through, doesn't let bill through
        {
            Console.WriteLine(word);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (word.Contains("bill"))  <--- bill never makes it here
            {
                Console.WriteLine("jarvis");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner if condition will never be ran. On the first loop you get the word        'hello' and the code in the outer if condition is executed. On the second loop         we have 'bill' and the outer if condition ignores that, hence the inner if conditon never runs. Try this instead: (place inside the for each loop)

```
if (word.Equals("hello"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
} 
else if (word.Contains("bill"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("jarvis");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
else
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```